# Complex query integration

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my main query I am working on which is just about finished.  The last thing I need to add is up to the last 10 phone numbers for the client.

```
    select distinct
        max(case when isnull(d.lastname,'')='' then d.name 
            else d.firstname+' '+(case when isnull(d.middlename,'')='' then '' else d.middlename+' ' end)+d.lastname+
                (case when isnull(d.suffix,'')='' then '' else ' '+d.suffix end) end)
        ,max(isnull(d.street1,p.street1))
        ,max(isnull(d.street2,''))
        ,max(d.city)
        ,max(isnull(d.state,p.state))
        ,max(isnull(d.zipcode,p.zipcode))
        ,max(dbo.stripnondigits(isnull(d.ssn,p.ssn)))
        ,'Add'
        ,'Primary Secondary Flag'
        ,max(m.number)
        , as 'phone1'
        , as 'phone2'
        , as 'phone3'
        , as 'phone4'
        , as 'phone5'
        , as 'phone6'
        , as 'phone7'
        , as 'phone8'
        , as 'phone9'
        , as 'phone10'
    from people p
    inner join master m
        on p.accountid = m.number
    inner join d_table d on p.debtorid=d.debtorid and isnull(d.jobname,'')=''
group by p.pid
```

I need the phone* columns to populate with the most recent phone number being `phone1` to the next most recent being `phone2` and so on.

Here is the query that grabs the last 10 phone numbers:

```
select ah.rownumber, ah.number, ah.dateadded, ah.phonenumber
from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by number order by dateadded desc) as 'rowNumber', number, dateadded, phonenumber
            FROM phones_master) ah
where rownumber <=10 
order by ah.number, ah.rownumber
```

This query will return up to (1 to 10) phone numbers for a person.

It groups on ah.number = m.number

I'm not sure how to combine these two queries into one.  Some accounts will return 1 phone number some could return 10.  Is it even possible to integrate these two queries?  The first one was written by another individual a long while ago, I just need to build the second query into it.

Comment: IF there is a common id column in both queries, then I think you can do something like where yourIDColumn in (yourSecondQuery), maybe?

Comment: @Laurence It seems distinct is not necessary as it returns 2165 rows with or without it of unique accounts.  There is a group by on p.pid that must not have gotten added.

Comment: @JamesWilson There's also nothing aliased to d that I can see, but it's referred to all over the query.

Comment: @Laurence it was a table join I left out I didn't think it was necessary, I will edit it.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you would be doing max(city) or max (state)...are you expecting 2 or 3 cities to be associated with a record and how does max(city) properly populate that?

Comment: @Twelfth it is ancient database tables set up probably 10 or more years ago.  using max was the best way would could figure out to narrow down the results with a group by.  As a person can be attached to many different accounts (master) which then branches out into many one to many's and many to many's.  Using more modern code I could probably re-write it to not have to use the max's, but not trying to re-do work unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: @Twelfth but yet a person could be associated with up to 10 different addresses, hundreds of accounts etc.  But I would have to make a very good argument to my superiors as to why rewriting working code would benefit them.

Comment: I think the point is that if you are using max, you could end up with components from different addresses

Comment: Ah, legacy system...legacy SQL always seems to be written funny.  My guess is there is a one to one relation to the address information being joined and max of one value is simply that value.  Proper way would be to include those fields in the group by statement and not taking a max of a varchchar() field, but as long as the one to one relation to the address table is true, you're fine...if you have 2 addresses for one user, it could be taking components from multiple addresses and combining it into the one row here.

Comment: @Laurence Ahh I see the concern now.  The current address is put into the master account for all accounts for the individual.  Then a history of previous addresses is put in a separate table that I don't join here.  So mixing up the addresses shouldn't happen with this query.  Unless I misunderstand something, which is always possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be an unecessary level of nesting in here, but this should work:

```
Select
    name,
    street1,
    street2,
    city,
    state,
    zipcode,
    ssn,
    action,
    flag,
    [number],
    [1] phone1,
    [2] phone2,
    [3] phone3,
    [4] phone4,
    [5] phone5,
    [6] phone6,
    [7] phone7,
    [8] phone8,
    [9] phone9,
    [10] phone10
From (
    select
        [name],
        street1,
        street2,
        city,
        state,
        zipcode,
        ssn,
        action,
        flag,
        p.[number],
        t.rn,
        t.phonenumber
    from (
        select
            max(case when 
                    isnull(d.lastname, '') = '' then d.name 
                    else d.firstname + ' ' + (
                    case when 
                        isnull(d.middlename, '') = '' then '' 
                        else d.middlename + ' ' 
                    end) + d.lastname + (
                    case when
                        isnull(d.suffix, '') = '' then '' 
                        else ' ' + d.suffix 
                    end) 
                end) [name],
            max(isnull(d.street1, p.street1)) street1,
            max(isnull(d.street2,'')) street2,
            max(d.city) city,
            max(isnull(d.state,p.state)) state,
            max(isnull(d.zipcode,p.zipcode)) zipcode,
            max(dbo.stripnondigits(isnull(d.ssn,p.ssn))) ssn,
            'Add' action,
            'Primary Secondary Flag' flag,
            max(m.number) [number]
        from
            people p
                inner join 
            master m
                on p.accountid = m.[number]
                inner join 
            d_table d 
                on p.debtorid = d.debtorid
        where
            isnull(d.jobname, '') = ''
        group by 
            p.pid
        ) p
        left outer join (
            select 
                ah.[number], 
                ah.rn, 
                ah.phonenumber
            from (
                select 
                    [number],
                    row_number() over (partition by [number] order by dateadded desc) rn, 
                    phonenumber
                from
                    phones_master
                ) ah
            where 
                rn <= 10 
        ) t
        on p.[number] = t.[number]
    ) x
pivot (
    max(phonenumber)
for
    rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
) as piv
```

Here's a version for older compatibility levels

```
Select
    name,
    street1,
    street2,
    city,
    state,
    zipcode,
    ssn,
    action,
    flag,
    [number],
    max(case rn when 1 then phonenumber end) phone1,
    max(case rn when 2 then phonenumber end) phone2,
    max(case rn when 3 then phonenumber end) phone3,
    max(case rn when 4 then phonenumber end) phone4,
    max(case rn when 5 then phonenumber end) phone5,
    max(case rn when 6 then phonenumber end) phone6,
    max(case rn when 7 then phonenumber end) phone7,
    max(case rn when 8 then phonenumber end) phone8,
    max(case rn when 9 then phonenumber end) phone9,
    max(case rn when 10 then phonenumber end) phone10
From (
    select
        [name],
        street1,
        street2,
        city,
        state,
        zipcode,
        ssn,
        action,
        flag,
        p.[number],
        t.rn,
        t.phonenumber
    from (
        select
            max(case when 
                    isnull(d.lastname, '') = '' then d.name 
                    else d.firstname + ' ' + (
                    case when 
                        isnull(d.middlename, '') = '' then '' 
                        else d.middlename + ' ' 
                    end) + d.lastname + (
                    case when
                        isnull(d.suffix, '') = '' then '' 
                        else ' ' + d.suffix 
                    end) 
                end) [name],
            max(isnull(d.street1, p.street1)) street1,
            max(isnull(d.street2,'')) street2,
            max(d.city) city,
            max(isnull(d.state,p.state)) state,
            max(isnull(d.zipcode,p.zipcode)) zipcode,
            max(dbo.stripnondigits(isnull(d.ssn,p.ssn))) ssn,
            'Add' action,
            'Primary Secondary Flag' flag,
            max(m.number) [number]
        from
            people p
                inner join 
            master m
                on p.accountid = m.[number]
                inner join 
            d_table d 
                on p.debtorid = d.debtorid
        where
            isnull(d.jobname, '') = ''
        group by 
            p.pid
        ) p
        left outer join (
            select 
                ah.[number], 
                ah.rn, 
                ah.phonenumber
            from (
                select 
                    [number],
                    row_number() over (partition by [number] order by dateadded desc) rn, 
                    phonenumber
                from
                    phones_master
                ) ah
            where 
                rn <= 10 
        ) t
        on p.[number] = t.[number]
    ) x
Group By
    name,
    street1,
    street2,
    city,
    state,
    zipcode,
    ssn,
    action,
    flag,
    [number]
```

Comment: Drats, I have to adjust my compatibility level for pivot tables.  Lemme see if the network guys can do that.

Comment: @JamesWilson please don't do that if it's a live system, you can write them by hand, it just sucks a bit more

Comment: I wasn't going to do it.  I just checked and my boss said to write them by hand using temp tables.  sorry for all the fuss.

Comment: @JamesWilson You don't need temp tables, see the second query.

Comment: Yeah looking at it now.  Getting an error: Column 'x.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. that I'm trying to work through.

Comment: If you copied the query when I first posted it then the last group by got detached from the query.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you.  going to play around with this but it look great.